# Images are loading okay on a Chrome tab, but returning 403 in React code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, http-status-code-403

I'm working on a React application that embeds images with `img` tag. And some images are not loading with 403 error:

[image]

However, it loads fine on another Chrome tab:

[image]

And this is the image tag after inspection:

[image]

What is the solution for this?

Comment: The server might have a referer check, IOW: it doesn't want you using direct links to this resource, but maybe download and host yourself, so that there server is not unduly bashed.

Comment: Works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/21wz84qn/).

Comment: @Solo Ha.. The image doesn't load for me.

Comment: @Keith How do I work around it?

Comment: You can just download the file, and copy to your server and reference that instead, @Solo The Image doesn't load for me either, you maybe have a referrer blocker plugin or something like that.

Comment: Worked fine until I did hard refresh, I have no idea what this is about.

Comment: When opening in a new tab, there is an error in the console : Failed to set referrer policy: The value '' is not one of 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin', 'same-origin', 'strict-origin', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', or 'unsafe-url'. The referrer policy has been left unchanged.

Answer (score 16):

The server checks the referer sent by the browser and will not return the image when the referer is from a different domain.

To prevent this, in many current browsers you can use the `referrerpolicy` attribute of the `img` tag to ask the browser to not send the referer:

```
<img referrerPolicy="no-referrer" src="https://www.host.net/image.png"  />
```

- [MDN on referrerpolicy attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-referrerpolicy)
- [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/referrerPolicy#Browser_compatibility)

Note on React: When using this in React, I found that it only works reliably when the `referrerPolicy` attribute is spelt with the capital P and appears before the src attribute.

---

Note that aside from the technical aspect, there is also a legal aspect. Linking to a resource on a different host can have legal consequences with regard to liability for damages as well as intellectual property issues. Please make sure it is okay for you to link to those resources on a different host.

Comment: I inspected the Network tab of the new tab, and it looks like the referrer policy is set as the browser default, that is no-referrer-when-downgrade.

Comment: @technophyle I have updated my answer. Try to move the referrerPolicy attribute before the src attribute and spell it with capital P.

Comment: [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21wz84qn/3/) shows that it is working.

Comment: also note that although the correct spelling of referrer has four Rs, it is spelt with three Rs, as `referer`, in the HTTP header.

Comment: worked for me while using the google auth in react web app to fetch the user profile image. thanks

Answer (score 2):

NineBerry is correct, but it is best practice to add an explicit [cross origin resource sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) permission to the headers in the server that is hosting the images (assuming you own that server), rather than ignoring the `referer`.

If you don't own the server that is hosting the images, then follow NineBerry's advice about the legalities.

From the [Mozilla CORS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP
>   headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are
>   permitted to read that information using a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img referrerPolicy="no-referrer" src="https://www.host.net/image.png"  />
```

worked for me while using google auth in React web app to fetch user profile pic URL